# Spring Boot JPA - Projection selecting all fields from table when has a collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I trying to get two fields and a @ElementCollection from entity using projection with interface, but the JPA are selecting all fields from my entity and when i remove the method that get the list of my @ElementCollection the JPA select the only two fields.

My entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    var name: String? = null,

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    var cpf: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false)
    var phoneNumber: String? = null,

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    var email: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "password_hash")
    var passwordHash: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "password_hash_recovery")
    var passwordHashRecovery: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "password_hash_recovery_date")
    var passwordHashRecoveryDate: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "self_employed", nullable = false)
    var selfEmployed: Boolean? = null,

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_photo", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var userPhoto: File? = null,

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_location", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var location: Location? = null,

    @Column(name = "rating_star", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var ratingStar: RatingStar = RatingStar.ONE,

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_area", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var area: Area? = null,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var workTimes: List<WorkTime> = arrayListOf(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contractor", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var contractorOrders: List<Order>? = arrayListOf(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "selfEmployed", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var selfEmployedOrders: List<Order>? = arrayListOf(),
) {

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "profiles_authorties",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
    )
    @Column(name = "authority")
    private val _authorities: MutableSet<ProfileAuthorities> = HashSet()

    init {
        _authorities.add(ProfileAuthorities.CLIENT)
    }

    fun setAsAdmin() =
        _authorities.add(ProfileAuthorities.ADMIN)

    fun getAuthorities(): Set<ProfileAuthorities> = _authorities


}
```

My interface for projection:

```
interface LoginUserProjection {
    fun getId(): Long
    fun getPasswordHash(): String
    fun getAuthorities(): Set<ProfileAuthorities>
}
```

The result query is:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_12_, user0_.id_area as id_area11_12_, user0_.cpf as cpf2_12_, user0_.email as email3_12_, user0_.id_location as id_loca12_12_, user0_.name as name4_12_, user0_.password_hash as password5_12_, user0_.password_hash_recovery as password6_12_, user0_.password_hash_recovery_date as password7_12_, user0_.phone_number as phone_nu8_12_, user0_.rating_star as rating_s9_12_, user0_.self_employed as self_em10_12_, user0_.user_photo as user_ph13_12_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select authoriti0_.user_id as user_id1_8_0_, authoriti0_.authority as authorit2_8_0_ from profiles_authorties authoriti0_ where authoriti0_.user_id=?
```

when i remove `fun getAuthorities(): Set<ProfileAuthorities>` from LoginUserProjection  the result is:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as col_0_0_, user0_.password_hash as col_1_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?
```

My repository method:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {

      fun <T> getUserProjectionById(id: Long, projection: Class<T>): T? 

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your repository method? I tried to reproduce this and strangely, in my case all the columns where fetched, even without the Set. Seems like there is an issue too here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1555

Comment: @AlkisMavridis the question has been updated, check it now